# using the result of foreach

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I am having a foreach loop in my code, and depending on the result of that foreach, it will redirect to another page. Below is the part of my code. I wanted to use the variable $email_number in my next page as well. Is there any way to take this email number to the other page.

```
foreach($result as $email_number) {
    $header = imap_headerinfo($connection, $email_number);
    $fromaddr = $header->from[0]->mailbox . "@" . $header->from[0]->host;
    $query = "select * from usergroup where email='$fromaddr'";

    while($line=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query);,MYSQL_ASSOC)){

     $email=$line['email'];
     $group=$line['group'];
    if($group == 1){
         header("Location: facilitator.php");
         }

         else {
             header("Location: new.php");
             }
    }
```

Comment: There're several ways to do it. Consider the use of `Session` at least

Comment: Probably the `while loop` is endless, and you have syntax error in your code near `mysql_query`

Comment: Is there a need to redirect, or couldn't you also just include new.php or facilitator.php?

Comment: How many rows are you expecting in `$result` and the sql query? These loops seem kind of pointless as you redirect on the first hit.